# Get data attribute of Datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I load some hidden data into a datalist and bind it with the [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

If a value selected, I want to get the value of the corresponding data attribute. This is my code:

```
<input list="browser" id="number">
<datalist id="browser">
    <option data-customValue="Abc" value="Firefox">1</option>
    <option data-customValue="Def" value="Chrome">2</option>
    <option data-customValue="Ghi" value="Explorer">3</option>
</datalist>
```

```js
$('#number').on('input', function() {
    var value = $('#browser').val();
    alert($('#browsers [value="' + value + '"]').data('customValue'));
});
```

In my case, I only get `undefined` as a response.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bd4rpztk/1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's two issues in your code. Firstly you need to get the `val()` from the `input` element, not the `datalist`. Secondly `data` attribute names should be lowercase otherwise it interferes with jQuery's internal cache. With that in mind, try this:

```
<input list="browser" id="number">
<datalist id="browser">
    <option data-customvalue="Abc" value="Firefox">1</option>
    <option data-customvalue="Def" value="Chrome">2</option>
    <option data-customvalue="Ghi" value="Explorer">3</option>
</datalist>
```

```js
$('#number').on('input', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    alert($('#browser [value="' + value + '"]').data('customvalue'));
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/bd4rpztk/5/)

Note that your logic may need to be amended to cater for people who are typing a value directly in to the `input`.